# Are Drupal sites naturally slow?

Tags: drupal

I know next to nothing about Drupal but I do have a question.  We had a site, written in straight HTML and PHP,  that loaded the main page in 1-2 seconds and made 25 requests to the server to get the data it needed.  A new Drupal version of the site  takes 5-6 seconds to load the main page, which is no more complicated than the old page, and makes 127 requests (I'm watching Firebug NET) to the server to get the data it needs.

Is this typical?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep a 3x performance hit is *natural* to Drupal, or most of large scale PHP application framework. Bootstraping Drupal is a costly operation as it requires loading a lot of files. Drupal is also known to perform too much DB queries in order to produce a single page.

The first step is to enable page caching and JS/CSS aggregation. This can be done from the administration page at *Administration >> Configuration >> Performance* (in Drupal 7).

But a 1-2 seconds load time on a lightweight PHP site is a sign of a either overloaded or badly tuned hosting. You should ensure you site is running in a recent PHP version (PHP is getting faster and faster with each version). Also enable [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php) (or any other opcache), even with the default settings it can greatly improve Drupal's performances. With APC, try increasing the shared memory size (eg. apc.shm_size = 64 in php.ini).

You should also try profiling your site to identify the actual bottle necks. With Drupal making several requests per page, the DB quickly becomes the bottle neck. Drupal support using multiple *slave* servers for *read* queries.

About the database, Drupal uses an internal cache which by default is stored in the database. So this cache does not deal well with overloaded database. Drupal's cache is pluggable. It can be configured to use [memcache](https://drupal.org/project/memcache), [redis](https://drupal.org/project/redis) or [mongodb](https://drupal.org/project/mongodb) for its storage. This could greatly reduce the load on the database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes drupal is slow.
Thats why we use caching mecahnisms if ur page is making too many requests

- See if u can aggregate ur CSS and JS(This will reduce number of
  HTML calls. u can do this from admin)
- Use CDN
- use memcache or varnish cache
- use page cache in apache.

Note:-please provide some actual data split up with some load testing tools

Comment: You suggest caching as a solution, but caching won't help the first time visitor, and a 5-6 second wait for every page will make them a last-time visitor.

Comment: no, not just caching. aggregating(into one file) JS,css will reduces the number of http requests made and also the size of js files. and a CDN() will help in reducing the load on ur app's server. if u don't like a CDN, u can set up a seperate static file server

Comment: What do you mean, "a separate static file server" ?  Thanks

Comment: like u can have separate web server ,like lighttpd, which serves the static js, css ,image files instead for ur drupal's server

Answer (score 1):

How much requests are sent to server? it also matters but drupal has solutions for it. Drupal combine all css files in to a single file to make server calls low, and similarly for js files.

But the speed also matters on server side code, database operations. Drupal is a powerful system which makes complex things easy (and yes easy things complex) and provides such capabilities so that a user can make a complete portal without a line of coding. But all these features come by the cost of performance. Internally drupal do lots of operations and it makes it slow.

Those operations includes views and block operations and the more complex the view / block / form is, the more operations there will be, and hence it will take more time.

Also if the site contents are increased then it will be become more slow. Because drupal consider every content as a node, and for all of your content types (for example news, cms pages, testimonials and so on) data is stored in a single node table (some other tables are also used, but your main contents are stored in node table). So when the contents are increased, the load on that single table is increased, which cause slow database operations, because the more big your table size is, the more operation time it will be taking.

I may be wrong, but Drupal is slow :P